# My wordpress comment reply not working, please i need a solution

Tags: wordpress, comments, reply

I formerly used a Wordpress theme where users could make comments on items I posted and also could make replies on comments made by other users on my Wordpress site.

I later changed my theme on Wordpress and I used a callback in my comment list in comment.php like this:

Then I coded the comment list form in my functions.php, and later noticed that when a user clicked the "reply" button below a comment, the page only reloaded but the comment reply is not working.

Please I really need help to resolve this. This is how I coded my "reply" form in my functions.php:  `$add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>`

Please is there any way I can resolve this? I will appreciate a reply... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if comment-reply.js is loaded on the page.

EDIT:
This should be already included in your theme's template files that handles the comment feature. View the page source to see if its included, if its not included then to include the this file. Goto functions.php and add this code.

```
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
```

Comment: Well it should have already be included if you are using wordpress templates. View the source to see if its included on that page. If its not included then check out my edit on how to included it.